# Why does my method not work with Regular Expressions?

Tags: java, regex

I have written this java method:

```
public boolean checkPatternMatching(String sourceToScan, String searchPattern) {

    boolean patternFounded;

    if (sourceToScan == null) {
        patternFounded = false;
    } else {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(searchPattern),
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sourceToScan);
        patternFounded = matcher.matches();
    }
    return patternFounded;
}
```

Now i want to check a String like "A". A method call like this returns a false value but why?

```
this.checkPatternMatching(stationShortcuts, "[a-zA-Z]")
```

Comment: Should I ask why you use `[a-zA-Z]` even though you use `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`?

Comment: @Keppil, good question? like it

Answer (score 6):

Replace following

```
Pattern.quote(searchPattern)
```

with

```
searchPattern
```

Otherwise the pattern is matched literally (special characters lose their meaning.)